# Cardinality of $\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathbb{C}}(A,\mathbb{C})$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

**Question**

Prove there is no finite generated algebra $A$ over $\mathbb{C}$ such that the cardinality of $\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathbb{C}}(A,\mathbb{C})$ is exactly $\aleph_0$.

I need to prove it using commutative algebra tools such as Hilbert basis & Nullstellensatz theorem, Noether normalization theorem, etc... but can't figure out how.

Thank you!

Comment: Is $A$ commuative?

Comment: Perhaps I'm making a silly mistake, but I'd be surprised if there was a reasonably accessible proof using just the Nullstellensatz - the first three or four ways that come to mind rely on at least one other result (Noether normalization, birationality of any variety to a hypersurface in $\Bbb P^n$, generic smoothness + some manifold theory, etc). Can you add some more context about where you've encountered this problem and what tools you have available to you?

Comment: $A$ is commutative indeed. This is a problem in my commutative algebra course. I can use Noether normalization theorem, Rabinowitsch trick, Hilbert Basis theorem or any outcomes from those. I said Hilbert Nullstellensatz because this question was in the chapter about HNT. sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Noether normalization says there's an injective map $R=\Bbb C[x_1,\cdots,x_n]\to A$ which makes $A$ into a finite $R$-algebra (where $n=\dim A$). This induces a map on the hom-sets $\operatorname{Hom}_{\Bbb C}(A,\Bbb C)\to\operatorname{Hom}_{\Bbb C}(R,\Bbb C)$. What can you say about this map? What can you say about $\operatorname{Hom}_{\Bbb C}(R,\Bbb C)$?

More details under the spoiler, though I encourage you to make an effort without looking under the spoiler first.

> This map of hom-sets is surjective and finite-to-one. Why? Every element in $A$ satisfies some polynomial with coefficients from $R$, so if you know what happens to elements of $R$, then you know what happens with elements of $A$, except possibly up to some finite ambiguity. Now all you have to do is to argue that $\operatorname{Hom}_{\Bbb C}(R,\Bbb C)$ is finite or at least the cardinality of the continuum, which should not be hard using the Nullstellensatz once you remember that maximal ideals are in bijection with maps to a field.

Comment: thank you! it was very helpful!

Comment: I'm glad to help. After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).